# Allow DragGesture to start over a Button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, gesture-recognition, draggesture

The code below presents a `View` in the middle of the screen, and allows you to drag that `View`. However, if you start the drag on the `Button`, the drag does not work. You need to drag on the area of the `View` around the `Button`.

Is there a way to make these two gestures know about each other, so that you can start the drag from anywhere in the `View`, even over the `Button`?

I'm imagining that putting a finger down on the `Button` would start both gestures as possibilities, and then if you would either lift up or start dragging to decide between the two.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var dragStartOffset: CGSize? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
             Button("Hello") { print("hello") }
             .padding(30)
             .background(.regularMaterial)
             .gesture(dragGesture)
             .offset(dragOffset)
        }
    }
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged { value in
                if dragStartOffset == nil {
                    dragStartOffset = dragOffset
                }
                dragOffset = dragStartOffset! + value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                dragStartOffset = nil
            }
    }
}

func +(a: CGSize, b: CGSize) -> CGSize { CGSize(width: a.width + b.width, height: a.height + b.height) }
```

Comment: Why button? Just use `TapGesture` on `Text("Hello")` and it will work with `DragGesture`.

Comment: `Button` provides a lot of stuff beyond `Text`, but if that is the only way, I will do it. I just tried it with `Text` that there is still an extra delay on the drag if you start over the button (the `minimumDistance` is not zero). I'd still like to know if there is a way to control that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.gesture(dragGesture)` try `.highPriorityGesture(dragGesture)`.